# Camel: using Saxon by default

Tags: apache-camel, xslt-2.0, saxon, fuseesb, jbossfuse

Is there a way to tell Camel to use the Saxon library by default, so I would not need to specify it in every XLST transformation? E.g.:

```
.to("xslt:my-file.xsl?transformerFactoryClass=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl")
```

Specifying it in every endpoint makes code less readable.

I've seen suggestions (though in some other contexts) on setting environment property:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

Would this somehow be possible to be set within single camel context?

P.S. I am using Camel 2.10, so the `saxon` parameter suggestion is unfortunately not an option yet...

Comment: How did you resolve it? I'm using camel 2.6

Comment: @MarcinErbel: eventually we moved to newer camel version and are using `saxon` property. I think there is no other way... - either specifying option per endpoint or via system property for whole JVM...

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/xslt) you can use:

```
.to("xslt:my-file.xsl?saxon=true")
```

which is much more readable

Comment: sorry, forgot to that say I am using camel 2.10, the `saxon` parameter is available as of 2.11... thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

The system property setting is working for the whole JVM, it is not good way for the container setting.

You can extend the XsltComponent to set the transformerFactoryClass for you as camel-2.11.x does or you can just add an constant which hold the option of transformerFactoryClass.